# Comparing solutions by law of total probability and by concept of independent events

Tags: probability

I was solving problems based on Bayes theorem from the book "A First Course in Probability by Sheldon Ross". The problem reads as follows:

> Independent trials consisting of rolling a pair of fair dice are performed. What is the probability that an outcome of 5 appears before an outcome of 7 when the outcome of a roll is the sum of the dice?

There are two solution given.

> **Solution 1 - Using geometric distribution**
>
> Let $E_n$ denote the event that no 5 or 7 appears on the first $n-1$ trials and a 5 appears on the $n$ th trial, then the desired probability is
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\right) 
> &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(E_n) \\
> &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1-\frac{10}{36}\right)^{n-1}\frac{4}{36} \\
> &= \frac{1}{9}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{13}{18}\right)^{n-1} \\
> &= \frac{1}{9}\frac{1}{1-\frac{13}{18}}=\frac{2}{5} \\
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> **Solution 2 - Using law of total probability**
>
> Let
>
> - $E$ be the event that a 5 occurs before a 7,
> - $F$ be the event that the first trial results in a 5,
> - $G$ be the event that it results in a 7, and
> - $H$ be the event that the first trial results in neither a 5 nor a 7.
>
> *Now we can obtain the desired probability, $P(E)$, by conditioning on the outcome of the first trial*.
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> P(E) 
> &= P(E|F)P(F) + P(E|G)P(G) + P(E|H)P(H)\\
> &= (1)\frac{4}{36} + (0)\frac{6}{36} + P(E)\frac{13}{18}\\
> &= \frac{2}{5}\\
> \end{align}
> $$

**My doubts**

1. Am I wrong in interpreting that the solution 1 is indeed based on geometric distrbution?
2. I dont understand the *italicized* statement in solution 2. Preceisely: how exactly "conditioning on the outcome of the first trial" is capable of giving desired probability across infinite trials?
3. Is "conditioning on the outcome of the first trial" possible in first (solution 1) approach? I understand that this may be very well not possible (is it so?). However I have made up this question just to get more clear idea about why its possible in solution 2 approach but not in solution 1 approach.
4. To generalize 2nd doubt, can we solve all geometric distribution problems with law of total probability? (Though I will come to know about this as I solve more geometric distribution problems and try to solve them with law of total probability, still need confirmation from experienced words.)